# Megasync installation on Lubuntu 18.04 32bit

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, lts, mega

is there a way to install megasync on 18.04 LTS Lubuntu?

Downloads in megasync has only 64bit version for (L)Ubuntu 18.04.
My only chance as a newbie is to go back to Lubuntu 16.04 LTS

TIA for any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the development of 32Bit versions of MEGAsync have been stoped since Ubuntu 17.10.

What you can do :

- Install older Ubuntu versions with 32bit
- Buy a new computer with 64Bit and install Ubuntu 18.04 in 64Bit, if you have checked that your current computer does not support 64bit

It's your decision...

Answer (score -1):

A 32 bit version for Ubuntu 18.04 is available, click through to the "Other downloads" link and navigate to here: https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/

Comment: This is not a link to an official Ubuntu distribution.  It is unsupported by Ubuntu.  Its integrity cannot be verified.  This download could be compromised.  It could contain malware, bugs, or other undesirables.  I would strongly advise against anyone downloading and using any unofficially supported OS.